# Mobile navbar shows options next to each other instead of underneath each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

The website URL is https://www.mh-rp.com/

I have this mobile navbar but the options should be underneath each other and not next to each other.
[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLAtM.png)

Comment: Hello Asif, thanks a lot. That did resolve it, but now the navbar is also displayed as a grid when not in mobile view, and that's not what I want.

Comment: Then I request you to elaborate your requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

In this case `display : grid` can solve your issue. But as It will work in all sizes so limiting it to mobile screen only, you can wrap your CSS inside media-query block `@media (max-width:1000px) {}` 
Try it:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .navigation {
    display: grid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one `<ul class="navigation" style="display: grid;">`

[image]